# Is there a means to set the owner of all objects in a PostgreSQL database at the same time?

Tags: postgresql, functions, ddl, metadata, owner

The Stack Overflow Q & A [Modify OWNER on all tables simultaneously in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348126/modify-owner-on-all-tables-simultaneously-in-postgresql) describes some nifty ways to change table and other objects to a specific user, and it works swimmingly, however all the suggestions seem to ignore the functions I created.

Is there a fairly easy way to reset the owner of ALL objects in the database, including the functions? Doing it by hand is highly undesirable.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Well, I didn't find a one-step process, but this takes care of all the objects I can see in my database:

```
update pg_class 
SET relowner = (SELECT oid FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'foo')
where relnamespace = (select oid 
                      from pg_namespace 
                      where nspname = 'public' 
                      limit 1);

update pg_proc 
set proowner = (select oid from pg_roles where rolname = 'foo')
where pronamespace = (select oid 
                      from pg_namespace 
                      where nspname = 'public' 
                      limit 1);
```

Comment: It's a good question (+1) -  -1 for your answer though - I wouldn't want anyone else to think it is ok to directly update system tables like this without being *very* sure they know what they are doing.

Comment: This is what I did and it worked.  It did exactly as I wanted.  Your attitude in protecting the users from themselves is unappreciated, as is your downvote for what was, in fact, the answer.

Comment: How do you know it didn't have some unexpected side-effect? Have you since tested your backups? Perhaps the next time you use [pg_upgrade](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgupgrade.html) you will find it doesn't work? Unless you can add some references to your answer (eg to the postgres [mailing lists](http://www.postgresql.org/community/lists/)) showing that this approach has no hidden problems, the downvote stays.

Comment: You are asking for proof that it will not break something, and my counterargument is that if you are downvoting something, you should include an explanation of what it will break and how/ why.  If you cannot, then the answer is not wrong, misleading, unuseful, or unhelpful, which are the criteria for a downvote.  The relationships in the metadata tables were not difficult to figure out in this case, upon a bit of examination, and as I said, it works swimmingly.  The burden of proof should be on the downvoter;  I expect you will have difficulties finding what this answer will break.

Comment: I will take the liberty of quoting @Erwin verbatim: "You should only ever manipulate system catalogs directly, if you know exactly what you are doing. It may have unexpected side effects. Or you can corrupt the database (or the whole database cluster) beyond repair". Erwin knows his stuff (and so do I). Check our reputation and past answers on the postgres tag here and on SO. My downvote is an expression of my opinion and I offer no proof because the docs are enough evidence for me (others can decide for themselves).

Comment: ["Normally, one should not change the system catalogs by hand, there are always SQL commands to do that. (For example, CREATE DATABASE inserts a row into the pg_database catalog — and actually creates the database on disk.) There are some exceptions for particularly esoteric operations, such as adding index access methods."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalogs.html#CATALOGS-OVERVIEW)

Comment: ...and, apparently, updating the owner of all objects in a database, for which there is still not a practical means of doing, going on 3 years later.  BTW, I have tested this in 8.4, 9.1, and 9.3, without issue. To the reader, YMMV, but it worked for me.

Comment: what's wrong with using Erwin's method? The fact that you have used the method without (apparent) issue gives me no confidence and neither should it: someone might equally say I've used RAID0 for years without issue.

Comment: Besides creating dynamic sql that you have to regurgitate, there is nothing "wrong" with his answer other than it being arguably more complicated; I have no power over your confidence, but after working with this rdbms for several years now, I definitely have confidence in it.

Comment: I also agree here, there is no advantage to this method. With @Erwin's method, I can see it audit it run it and if something blows up I know what did it. I can bring the DB back from back up and bisect the batch and try again. With this method, I'm flying blind and it's objectively more dangerous.

Comment: If you want all database objects just use `REASSIGN OWNED` which Erwin mentions

Comment: @EvanCarroll that does not work for all database objects.

Answer (score 26):

You should only ever **manipulate system catalogs** directly, if you know exactly what you are doing. It may have unexpected side effects. Or you can corrupt the database (or the whole database cluster) beyond repair.

[Jeremy's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9709/3684), while basically doing the trick, is **not advisable** for the general public. It unconditionally changes all functions in a schema. Are you sure there are no system functions affected or functions installed by an additional module?
It would also be pointless to change the owner of functions that already belong to the designated owner.

First, check if [**`REASSIGN OWNED`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reassign-owned.html) could work for you:

> change the ownership of database objects owned by a database role

You have to list all roles to be disowned explicitly. But it **also reassigns functions**.

To assign *all* functions (and no other objects) in a given schema to a new owner (optionally regardless of previous owner):

```
SELECT string_agg('ALTER FUNCTION '|| oid::regprocedure || ' OWNER TO foo;', E'\n') AS ddl
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc
WHERE  pronamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
-- AND proowner <> 'foo'::regrole
-- AND proname ~~ 'f_%'
```

This generates the [**canonical SQL commands `ALTER FUNCTION ...`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterfunction.html) to change **all** functions (in the specified schema). Inspect the commands before executing - one by one or all at once:

```
ALTER FUNCTION public.bar(text, text) OWNER TO foo;
ALTER FUNCTION public.foo(x integer) OWNER TO foo;
...
```

The cast to `regprocedure` produces a valid function name with parameters, double-quoted where necessary, schema-qualified where necessary for the current `search_path`.

Also using the [object identifier types `regnamespace` and `regrole`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) for simplicity.

I added some commented `WHERE` clauses you might want to use to filter the results.

You *could* put all of this into a `DO` statement or a function like demonstrated in this related answer:

- [Drop all functions in a namespace? (Execute generated DDL commands?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317942/939860)

For Postgres **9.4 or older**:

```
SELECT string_agg('ALTER FUNCTION ' || oid::regprocedure || ' OWNER TO foo;', E'\n') AS ddl
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc p
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE  n.nspname = 'public'
-- AND p.proowner <> (SELECT oid FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'foo')
-- AND p.proname ~~ 'f_%'
```

The aggregate function [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) requires PostgreSQL 9.0 or later. In older version substitute with `array_agg()` and `array_to_string()`.

Answer (score 1):

I use this function to alter the owner of tables, functions, types, etc.
You can change the query of the cursors to adapt it to your needs.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_setowner(varchar(50), boolean) RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
p_owner ALIAS FOR $1;
p_debug ALIAS FOR $2;
v_i integer := 0;
v_sql text;

--  CURSORS
-- SCHEMA
pesquemas CURSOR FOR
    SELECT quote_ident(schema_name) as nombre_esquema from information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
    and schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema') ORDER BY 1 ASC;

-- TABLE
ptablas CURSOR FOR
    SELECT quote_ident(table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(table_name) as nombre_tabla, * FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    AND table_type <> 'FOREIGN TABLE' ORDER BY 1 ASC;

-- FUNCTION
pfunciones CURSOR FOR
    SELECT quote_ident(b.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(a.proname) || '(' || pg_catalog.oidvectortypes(a.proargtypes) || ')' as nombre_function 
    FROM pg_proc a  INNER JOIN pg_namespace b on a.pronamespace = b.oid 
    WHERE b.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND proisagg = 'f'
    AND a.proname not like 'fsym_%' AND a.proname not like 'dblink%' ORDER BY 1 ASC;

-- SEQUENCE
psecuencias CURSOR FOR
    SELECT quote_ident(sequence_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(sequence_name) as nombre_secuencia FROM information_schema.sequences
    WHERE sequence_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') ORDER BY 1 ASC;

-- TYPE
ptipos CURSOR FOR
    SELECT quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(t.typname) as nombre_tipo
    FROM pg_type t
    LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace 
    WHERE (t.typrelid = 0 OR (SELECT c.relkind = 'c' FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid)) 
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el WHERE el.oid = t.typelem AND el.typarray = t.oid)
    AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') ORDER BY 1 ASC;


BEGIN
--  CHECK LOGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_user WHERE usename = p_owner) THEN                     
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Login role not exists --> %', p_owner
            USING HINT = 'Please specify correct login and try again.';
    END IF;

    v_i = 0;
    if (p_debug) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '--########## CHANGE SCHEMA OWNER ##########--';
    END IF;
    FOR resquema IN pesquemas LOOP
        v_sql = 'ALTER SCHEMA ' || resquema.nombre_esquema || ' OWNER TO ' || quote_ident(p_owner) || ';';
        if (p_debug) THEN RAISE NOTICE '%', v_sql; END IF;
        EXECUTE v_sql;
        v_i = v_i + 1;
    END LOOP;
    if (p_debug) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '--@@@@@@ SCHEMAS WITH OWNER % TOTAL = % @@@@@@--', p_owner, CAST(v_i AS VARCHAR);
    END IF;

    v_i = 0;
    if (p_debug) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '--########## CHANGE TABLE OWNER ##########--';
    END IF;
    FOR rtables IN  ptablas LOOP
        v_sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' || rtables.nombre_tabla || ' OWNER TO ' || quote_ident(p_owner) || ';';
        if (p_debug) THEN RAISE NOTICE '%', v_sql; END IF;
        EXECUTE v_sql;
        v_i = v_i + 1;
    END LOOP;
    if (p_debug) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '--@@@@@@ TABLES WITH OWNER % TOTAL = % @@@@@@--', p_owner, CAST(v_i AS VARCHAR);
    END IF;

    v_i = 0;
    if (p_debug) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '--########## CHANGE FUNCTION OWNER ##########--';
    END IF;
    FOR rfunction IN  pfunciones LOOP
        v_sql = 'ALTER FUNCTION ' || rfunction.nombre_function || ' OWNER TO ' || quote_ident(p_owner) || ';';
        if (p_debug) THEN RAISE NOTICE '%', v_sql; END IF;
        EXECUTE v_sql;
        v_i = v_i + 1;
    END LOOP;
    if (p_debug) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '--@@@@@@ FUNCTIONS WITH OWNER % TOTAL = % @@@@@@--', p_owner, CAST(v_i AS VARCHAR);
    END IF;

    v_i = 0;
    if (p_debug) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '--########## CHANGE SEQUENCE OWNER ########## --';
    END IF;
    FOR rsecuencias IN  psecuencias LOOP
        v_sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' || rsecuencias.nombre_secuencia || ' OWNER TO ' || quote_ident(p_owner) || ';';             
        if (p_debug) THEN RAISE NOTICE '%', v_sql; END IF;
        EXECUTE v_sql;
        v_i = v_i + 1;
    END LOOP;
    if (p_debug) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '--@@@@@@ SEQUENCES WITH OWNER % TOTAL = % @@@@@@--', p_owner, CAST(v_i AS VARCHAR);
    END IF;

    v_i = 0;
    if (p_debug) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '--########## CHANGE TYPE OWNER ##########--';
    END IF;
    FOR rtipos IN  ptipos LOOP                
        v_sql = 'ALTER TYPE ' || rtipos.nombre_tipo || ' OWNER TO ' || quote_ident(p_owner) || ';';                
        if (p_debug) THEN RAISE NOTICE '%', v_sql; END IF;
        EXECUTE v_sql;
        v_i = v_i + 1;
    END LOOP;
    if (p_debug) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '--@@@@@@  TYPES WITH OWNER % TOTAL = % @@@@@@--', p_owner, CAST(v_i AS VARCHAR);
    END IF;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Then I just execute (if you want debugging output simply set the second parameter to true):

```
SELECT fn_setowner('demo', false);
DROP FUNCTION fn_setowner(varchar(30), boolean);
```

Comment: Note that `pg_proc.proisagg` is replaced in pg 11. [The release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/release-11.html) say: *Replace system table `pg_proc`'s `proisagg` and `proiswindow` with `prokind` (Peter Eisentraut)`*

Answer (score 1):

This should work for functions:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for fnc in `psql -qAt -c "SELECT  '\"' || p.proname||'\"' || '(' || pg_catalog.pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid) || ')' FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc p ON p.pronamespace = n.oid WHERE n.nspname = 'public';" YOUR_DB`
do
  psql -c "alter function $fnc owner to NEW_OWNER" YOUR_DB
done
```

Answer (score 0):

just dump database *schema* only
then use GnSa or "Grep n Sed away"

```
pg_dump DBNAME -s | grep -E "OWNER TO" | sed -E "s/(OWNER TO )ownerA/\1ownerB/" | psql DBNAME
```