# Change owner of all schema objects

Tags: postgresql, schema, plpgsql, role

I want to change the owner of all objects in a schema. To do this I use the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION chown(in_schema VARCHAR, new_owner VARCHAR) 
RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
  object_types VARCHAR[];
  object_classes VARCHAR[];
  object_type record;

  r record;
BEGIN
  object_types = '{type,table,sequence,index,table,view}';
  object_classes = '{c,t,S,i,r,v}';

  FOR object_type IN 
      SELECT unnest(object_types) type_name, 
                unnest(object_classes) code
  loop
    FOR r IN 
      EXECUTE '
          select n.nspname, c.relname 
          from pg_class c, pg_namespace n 
          where n.oid = c.relnamespace 
            and nspname = ''' || in_schema || '''
            and relkind = ''' || object_type.code || ''''
    loop 
      raise notice 'Changing ownership of % %.% to %', 
                  object_type.type_name, 
                  r.nspname, r.relname, new_owner;
      EXECUTE 
        'alter ' || object_type.type_name || ' '
                 || r.nspname || '.' || r.relname 
                 || ' owner to ' || new_owner;
    END loop;
  END loop;

  FOR r IN 
    SELECT  p.proname, n.nspname,
       pg_catalog.pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid) args
    FROM    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
    JOIN    pg_catalog.pg_proc p
    ON      p.pronamespace = n.oid
    WHERE   n.nspname = in_schema
  LOOP
    raise notice 'Changing ownership of function %.%(%) to %', 
                 r.nspname, r.proname, r.args, new_owner;
    EXECUTE 
       'alter function ' || r.nspname || '.' || r.proname ||
       '(' || r.args || ') owner to ' || new_owner;
  END LOOP;

  FOR r IN 
    SELECT * 
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict d 
      ON d.dictnamespace = n.oid
    WHERE n.nspname = in_schema
  LOOP
    EXECUTE 
       'alter text search dictionary ' || r.nspname || '.' || r.dictname || 
       ' owner to ' || new_owner;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

(https://www.garysieling.com/blog/postgres-change-owner-all-objects-in-schema)

Unfortunately, the function doesn't work as expected in some cases.

```
CREATE ROLE user_old LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE user_new LOGIN;

CREATE SCHEMA schema_a AUTHORIZATION user_old;

CREATE TABLE schema_a.test_a (
id serial NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT test_a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE schema_a.test_a OWNER TO user_old;

SELECT chown('schema_a', 'user_new')

NOTICE: Changing ownership of sequence schema_a.test_a_id_seq to user_new
ERROR: cannot change owner of sequence “test_a_id_seq”
DETAIL: Sequence “test_a_id_seq” is linked to table “test_a”.
KONTEXT: SQL statement “alter sequence schema_a.test_a_id_seq owner to user_new”
PL/pgSQL function chown(character varying,character varying) line 27 at EXECUTE

********** Error **********

ERROR: cannot change owner of sequence “test_a_id_seq”
SQL state: 0A000
Detail: Sequence “test_a_id_seq” is linked to table “test_a”.
Context: SQL statement “alter sequence schema_a.test_a_id_seq owner to user_new”
PL/pgSQL function chown(character varying,character varying) line 27 at EXECUTE
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: why not https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reassign-owned.html ?..

Comment: BTW, you can largely simplify function handling with a cast to `regprocedure`. Details: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9710/3684

Comment: `REASSIGN OWNED` changes ownership for ALL objects owned by one role to another, unrestricted, which may not be what is desired, if the change is needs to be restricted only one DB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to avoid mentionned error, try changing the order:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.chown(in_schema character varying, new_owner character varying)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  object_types VARCHAR[];
  object_classes VARCHAR[];
  object_type record;

  r record;
BEGIN
  object_types = '{type,table,table,sequence,index,view}';
  object_classes = '{c,t,r,S,i,v}';

  FOR object_type IN
      SELECT unnest(object_types) type_name,
                unnest(object_classes) code
  loop
    FOR r IN
      EXECUTE format('
          select n.nspname, c.relname
          from pg_class c, pg_namespace n
          where n.oid = c.relnamespace
            and nspname = %I
            and relkind = %L',in_schema,object_type.code)
    loop
      raise notice 'Changing ownership of % %.% to %',
                  object_type.type_name,
                  r.nspname, r.relname, new_owner;
      EXECUTE format(
        'alter %s %I.%I owner to %I'
        , object_type.type_name, r.nspname, r.relname,new_owner);
    END loop;
  END loop;

  FOR r IN
    SELECT  p.proname, n.nspname,
       pg_catalog.pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid) args
    FROM    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
    JOIN    pg_catalog.pg_proc p
    ON      p.pronamespace = n.oid
    WHERE   n.nspname = in_schema
  LOOP
    raise notice 'Changing ownership of function %.%(%) to %',
                 r.nspname, r.proname, r.args, new_owner;
    EXECUTE format(
       'alter function %I.%I (%s) owner to %I', r.nspname, r.proname, r.args, new_owner);
  END LOOP;

  FOR r IN
    SELECT *
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict d
      ON d.dictnamespace = n.oid
    WHERE n.nspname = in_schema
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format(
       'alter text search dictionary %I.%I owner to %I', r.nspname, r.dictname, new_owner );
  END LOOP;
END;
$function$
```

Also [read](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reassign-owned.html) about `REASSIGN OWNED`

Alse [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html) is info on `relkind` if you wander why I changed the order:

> r = ordinary table, i = index, S = sequence, v = view, m =
>   materialized view, c = composite type, t = TOAST table, f = foreign
>   table

Comment: I'll check `REASSIGN`. The function is still not working. Can you test it?

Comment: yes - `object_types` array had extra "table" next to last key. now should work

Comment: Now the function works just fine, but it seems to miss `END loop;`, `END;` and `$$` before `LANGUAGE plpgsql;`. I do not understand why your function is much shorter than the one posted in the question.

Comment: It was shorter, because iterm "ate" the tail - updated with real definition

Comment: @LunarSea: My downvote is for concatenating user input into a dynamic SQL string without escaping. ***NEVER*** do this, not even for supposedly very private functions. Identifiers have to be treated as user input and escaped. Else you are open to SQL injection and other lesser problems. How to fix? See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18386034/939860 (Vao, I'll happily I'll rescind the vote if you fix this and ping me.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter hey, thanks for taking care. I must be destructed or wanted a fats win - usually I take care or dynamic sql formatting. Here just specified a right order for OP's function to work. Anyway rewrote above with proper(hopefully) format. Sorry for taking your time for this.

Comment: @VaoTsun: Much better!