# How to grant all privileges on a database?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

There are many almost-duplicates to this question and all I found so far were wrong and/or incomplete, so I feel we need a canonical answer.

**In PostgreSQL, how can I grant all permissions on a database to a user, without giving them SUPERUSER permissions?**

This includes all *tables*, *sequences*, *types*, *triggers*, *indexes*, *procedures* and whatever *other objects* are currently in the database and any objects that are created in the database at a later time, by this user or others. Of course, it also includes to ability to create objects in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is hardly practical - you would typically use a superuser for this. Because, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-priv.html):

> The right to modify or destroy an object is always the privilege of the owner only.

[And:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-DESCRIPTION-OBJECTS)

> The right to drop an object, or to alter its definition in any way, is
>   not treated as a grantable privilege; it is inherent in the owner, and
>   cannot be granted or revoked. (However, a similar effect can be
>   obtained by granting or revoking membership in the role that owns the
>   object; see below.) The owner implicitly has all grant options for the
>   object, too.

So, for a non-superuser to have these privileges, too, it would have to be granted membership (directly or indirectly) in all roles that are allowed to create objects.

```
GRANT any_role TO admin_role;
```

Granting membership in a superuser role does not make the member a superuser.

> The role attributes `LOGIN`, `SUPERUSER`, `CREATEDB`, and `CREATEROLE` can be
>   thought of as special privileges, but they are never inherited as
>   ordinary privileges on database objects are.

**But** the member role can now `SET ROLE` and *become* superuser. May or may not be what you want.

Then, as owner, `admin_role` can also `GRANT` any additional privileges (that may have been revoked) himself.

**Or** you set up a regime that assigns ownership of all existing and future objects to a role and grant membership in that role only. The quick way to do that for all objects of given roles is [`REASSIGN OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reassign-owned.html). Related:

- [Is there a means to set the owner of all objects in a PostgreSQL database at the same time?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9708/is-there-a-means-to-set-the-owner-of-all-objects-in-a-postgresql-database-at-the/9710#9710)

But would you even want to grant ownership on objects in the system catalog, too? Those are owned by the superuser `postgres` in default setup.

---

Instead, I would use a superuser where "all" privileges are needed. And grant only required privileges ( incl. `CREATEDB` and `CREATEROLE`) to an admin role. A recipe for a powerful admin role (without *all* privileges):

- [How to manage DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for USERs on a DATABASE vs SCHEMA?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema/117661#117661)

Comment: Ok, at least this is a good explanation why there are no answers: because it is not possible. In that case I asked the wrong question (XY problem), I'll ask a new one.